# How to make a simple check that the game was recompiled?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I have read that it is very easy to hack and recompile an unity game. Also, I read that they have a function (provided by the engine) to determine that the game has been recompiled.

e.g. I release the game,
a bad guy hacks it and publish as his own,
but somewhere in the depth of the code still there is a check that the game has been recompiled,
so that I can display some note to the user or to make the game unplayable.

Is it easy to hack a cocos game?
Do I need to worry about it?
How to make a small copy protection for my game?

Comment: MikhailSh from cocos forum helped me a lot with the solution of this problem. http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/is-it-easy-to-hack-and-recompile-a-cocos-game/27832

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have read that it is very easy to hack and recompile an unity game.
>   Also, I read that they have a function (provided by the engine) to
>   determine that the game has been recompiled.

Yes, Unity has a function to determine if your game has been **de-compiled** and **recompiled** or **modified** in any way. But the hacker would be **smart** enough to modify what that function **returns**, before **re-compiling** the game. Any protection code you write can be **modified** or **removed** by the **hacker**.

> I release the game, a bad guy hacks it and publish as his own, but
>   somewhere in the depth of the code still there is a check that the
>   game has been recompiled, so that I can display some note to the user
>   or to make the game unplayable.

Some one will always try to hack your game. This will be likely if your game is famous and is played by many. Displaying some note to the user wont stop hackers from hacking your game. Making the game unplayable wont either.

> Is it easy to hack a cocos game? Do I need to worry about it? How to
>   make a small copy protection for my game?

Any game can be **hacked**. Depending on the hacker's **experience**, the hack could be **hard** or **easy** for them. You **don't** need to **worry** about this. **Large** game companies have **dedicated** team of **programmers** that **protects** their **games** but it only takes hackers **weeks** or **months** to remove every **protection** from the **game** and make the game **playable** once again.

Spend most of your time making **great** games and make the game cost to be **affordable**, then **less** people will **pirate** your game. There is **no way** you can **fully** stop people from **hacking** your game no **matter** the **programming language** or **operating system** the game was designed for.

**EDIT**:

1. To add a simple protection you, should **obfuscate** your C++ code.**Obfuscation** will make your code more **un-readable**. For example, if you have a class called `PlayerInfo` that contains the score, Obfuscation will rename the class name to `Esfjhsakm4`. The hacker would have to go through everything one by one to realize what's going on in your app. You can google C/C++ **Obfuscator** for more information.
2. Another way to protect your code is to give your game a limit of player score over time. Maybe if a player points goes from **0 to 100** within a second and you know that is not **possible** with your game mechanics, you can **detect** this as a hack and then take action.
3. If this is a network game, make the game so that players would have to **register** and **sign in** to play. Then you can ban the player's account if you catch them cheating. Also ban their **IP Address** for **3 days** then lift the ban after **3 days** but don't lift the ban on the **player's account**.
4. Detect if an item has been unlocked while the user has not played the level that is required to unlock that item.

The big advice is that you don't let user know that you detected hack in their game. Just take a background action such as changing the games mode from **easy** to **hard**, **banning the player** and make the game annoying. If you **close** the game when hack is detected, they will remove the **code** that closes the game.

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your answer!

Comment: Secondly, I understand that no one protection will not save 100%, I just want to find easy to implement way to set a minimum of protection, so that not any schoolchild can copy the game. I also read that there have been cases when this simple protection was effective, since not all hackers want to read all of your code.

Comment: Also, if the code is written in C ++, it complicates the hacking, but I do not know how much. I'm not too familiar with the Reverse Engineering.

Comment: Yes, it's harder because you can't decompile it back to c++ like you can decompile java classes to java. Instead it's decompiled to assembler.

Comment: Makalele, Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @Makalele, you add protection to make it harder for the hacker. Without protection or obfuscation, it would take the hacker about 10 minutes to find find out how your game work. With protection, it will take the hacker about 30 minutes but it wont stop them. I am saying this from experience. For Makele's comment about assembly, any hacker that can't read, write assembly code is NOT a hacker. They are people that use other hacker's tool  to hack apps. A real hacker reads and writes in assembly.

Comment: I just modified my answer to show ways you can detect cheat in your game and what action you should take. If this question is about detecting when someone steals your game and out it on sale on another website then you are on your own because the hacker would remove anything network code you use to send that information back to you.